# How to handle generic result with AspectJ?

Tags: generics, aop, aspectj

I have an aspect (written with aspectj syntax `public aspect ....`) that manipulates the result of many methods that return a `Collection` in order to paginate the result.

I can't (or I don't know how to) use generics in advices, so wherever I call one of the advised methods I get the warning

`unchecked conversion when advice applied at shadow method-call(java.util.Collection ...), expected java.util.Collection<T> but advice uses java.util.Collection [Xlint:uncheckedAdviceConversion]`

How can I get rid of this?

Stefano

-- Adding aspect code excerpt

```
public aspect PaginationSupportAspect extends ServiceSupportAspect {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaginationSupportAspect.class);

    private pointcut paginate(Criteria criteria) : call(Collection org.jcz.persistence.Service+.*(Criteria));

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    Collection around(Criteria criteria, Service service) : paginate(criteria) && target(service) {
        log.trace(String.format("Executing <%s> @ <%s>", this.getClass(), thisJoinPoint.toLongString()));

        return doPaginate(proceed(criteria, service), criteria.getPagination(), service);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param source
     * @param criteria
     * @return
     */
    private <T extends EntitySupport> Collection<T> doPaginate(Collection<T> source, Pagination pagination, Service<T> service) {
        // IMPLEMENTATION OMITTED BECAUSE IT'S QUITE LONG

        // What it does is to create another Collection<T> that holds the pagination coordinates (page number, size, count) 
        // and only the elements of the requested page
    }

}
```

Usage example

```
Collection<MyEntity> entities = myEntityService.findAll(criteria);
```

That's where I get the warning

Comment: @m0skit0, I added the code at the end of the question

Comment: It is nearly impossible to recreate your situation because of the many omissions in your code example. You use classes/interfaces like Criteria, EntitySupport, MyEntity, Pagination, Service, ServiceSupportAspect and it is quite hard to understand how they relate to each other. I would need to see more code or get a minimal, self-contained sample (maybe with dummy classes) which I could compile and run in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wait a minute, maybe I reproduced it, see below.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? I have explained to you why the problem happens and how to reproduce it. I cannot change AspectJ's limitations for you though. Thanks.

Comment: Added you an upvote. But can't mark it as solved though. Thanks anyways for the help.

Comment: Thanks. You are the author, you should be able to accept it by just clicking on the checkmark below my answer's upvote count.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news: I do not know how to avoid the warning because I am not so proficient in Java generics, specifically not in connection with AspectJ because there not everything you might expect is syntactically allowed, e.g. binding the `target()` to a parametrised type (because of type erasure limitations).

Probably you are having the same problem as [this one](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg13923.html) on the AspectJ mailing list.

The good news: I finally managed to reproduce your problem with a minimal code sample, using a lot of dummy classes, doing some educated guesses about how you use them in your application:

**Dummy/helper classes/aspects:**

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;
public class EntitySupport {}
```

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;
public class MyEntity {}
```

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;
public class Pagination {}
```

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;

public class Criteria {
    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return new Pagination();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Service<T> {
    public Collection<T> findAll(Criteria criteria) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;
public abstract aspect ServiceSupportAspect {}
```

**Your aspect, slightly changed:**

```java
package org.jcz.persistence;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public aspect PaginationSupportAspect extends ServiceSupportAspect {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PaginationSupportAspect.class);

    private pointcut paginate(Criteria criteria) :
        call(Collection org.jcz.persistence.Service+.*(Criteria)) && args(criteria);

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    Collection around(Criteria criteria, Service service) : paginate(criteria) && target(service) {
        log.trace(String.format("Executing <%s> @ <%s>", this.getClass(), thisJoinPoint.toLongString()));
        return doPaginate(proceed(criteria, service), criteria.getPagination(), service);
    }

    private <T extends EntitySupport> Collection<T> doPaginate(
            Collection<T> source, Pagination pagination, Service<T> service)
    {
        System.out.println("doPaginate");
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

**And now a little driver application reproducing the Xlint warning:**

```java
import java.util.Collection;

import org.jcz.persistence.Criteria;
import org.jcz.persistence.MyEntity;
import org.jcz.persistence.Service;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service<MyEntity> myEntityService = new Service<MyEntity>();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Collection<MyEntity> entities = myEntityService.findAll(criteria);
        System.out.println("Found entities: " + entities);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone else can make something of it which I cannot. The best I could do was reproduce it. I will try to point Andy Clement to this post. Good luck!